# Extracting all information within polygons from separate feature classes (layers)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, union

I have a model with 2 layers. The first layer contain information about soil, vegetation etc in a large area. The second layer shows property boundaries within this large area.

Is it possible to create a model that finds all the information about soil and vegetation within the boundaries of each property?

Answer (score 3):

To do this try using the [Union](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) tool which:

> Computes a geometric union of the input features. All features and
>   their attributes will be written to the output feature class.